# SSIS SQL Task - "Parameter name is unrecognized"

Tags: ssis

I have a SQL Task that needs to run a simple update to update a single row.

I have set the SQLStatement to:

```
update agency set AgencyLastBatchSeqNo = ? where agencyID = ?
```

On the Parameter Mapping page I gave set Parameter 0 and Parameter 1 to variables that I know contain the right values. I have also set the Parameter Name values correctly.

In the database, the column AgencyLastBatchSeqNo  is an int, AgencyID is a big int. Does anyone have a reference to find what the data types map to in SSIS? I have guessed at SHORT for the int and LONG for the big int.

When I run the task I get the following error:

> **[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "update agency set AgencyLastBatchSeqNo = ? where AgencyID = ?" failed with the following
>   error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.**

Could anyone please suggest what may be wrong?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The answer to this is to change the Parameter Name value in the Parameter Mapping screen.

Given the following query

```
SELECT Id, AnimalName FROM dbo.Farm WHERE Farm_id = ?
```

Assuming my Parameter is an integer Variable named User::Farm_id
Choose the following values on the Parameter Mapping Screen

```
Variable Name  -   User::Farm_id
Direction      -   Input
Data Type      -   LONG
Parameter Name -   0
Parameter Size -   -1
```

Originally the Parameter Name will be "NewParameterName". Simply change this to the ordinal position of your variable marker ("?")

Comment: I was putting the NAME of the parameter in Parameter Name (shock horror) and was tearing my hair out!

Comment: So a name is not actually a name.. but an ordinal position.. how intuitive... not. (Thanks by the way!)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using more than 1 parameter then in the execute sql task window go to parameter mapping and set the parameter name to 0,1,2,3....depending on the number of parameter and the parameter size to -1..
This must be helpful to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for answer a question that was likely to come up.  It certainly did for me.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you don't mention is your connection type.  I assume you are not using ADO.Net since the parameter marking in that case is not a ?.  For the other types of connection, parameters are named as follows:
ADO (not ADO.Net) connection: parameter names are Param1, Param2...
ODBC connection: parameter names are 1,2,3...
OLEDB connection: parameter names are 0,1,2...

For the variable types (they are different in the parameter mapping section than in any other area of SSIS) I typically use Long for Int's and I typically leave the length set to -1. I believe that a Long will work for both Int's and Bigint's.

Answer (score 1):

See **[SSIS data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)**.

```
   int = DT_I4  (4 byte integer) = Int32 variable
bigint = DT_I8  (8 byte integer)  = Int64 variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're quoting your values, and that you don't have typos in your column names.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the parameter mappings any trailing blanks after the parameter name can cause this message too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Parameter Mapping and change Mapped Parameter_Name = 0 instead of using default name.
and for next parameter it should be 1. and so on...

Note:- you have to change the "Data Type" as per the value.

it will just take place on the occurrence of "?"